# Getting error: Incorrect syntax near "-" while executing batch file

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm using this command:

```
SQLCMD -S %ServerName% -E -d %DBName% -Q "exec sp_Cust_Info %1 %2"
```

and get an error:

> Incorrect syntax near "-"

Please help me with this

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Comment: That error is a SQL error, and you've provided us with the command line command. At a guess, you're passing a `varchar` value that isn't quoted. If you're passing numerical values, then the problem is in `exec sp_Cust_Info`, and we can't see the DDL fo that to even begin to debug it.

Comment: Also, if they are numerical values, it should be `exec sp_Cust_Info %1, %2`?

Comment: parameters passed are date type

Comment: Dates need to be put in quotes too. If you are specifying your date with "-" separator that'll be your issue.

Comment: *"parameters passed are date type"* That isn't a numerical data type.

Comment: So, how to pass two date parameters while executing batch file from cmd line

Comment: Is this Windows? If so, it supports parametrisation with the `-v` switch.